# How to convert text file to csv file using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, export-to-csv

I have text file like this

```
data11
data12
data13
data14
data15
data21
data22
data23
data24
data25
.......
```

like this 2000 rows.

I want all these values in .csv file like

```
Image     prob1     prob2     prob3     truevalue
data11    data12    data13    data14     data15
data21    data22    data23    data24     data25
```

can anybody provide a shell script for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 cat file|xargs -n5
```

works for the given example.

If this doesn't help, please tell the exact requirements.

#### update, add the fixed title

```
 cat <(echo "a b c d e") file|xargs -n5
```

if you want better format in output:

```
 cat <(echo "a b c d e") file|xargs -n5 |column -t
```

Comment: yeah i got 5 values i want them in 5 columns adding names at top in .csv like imagenumber   prob1    prob2   prob3   true.

Comment: @BHAV247 the title is just fixed text, isn't it?